# "input/output error during read on /dev/sda" during installation

Tags: system-installation, 10.04

At the moment my laptop does not have any OS. I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 using a live cd, which runs perfectly, but after the initial installation steps it shows an

> input/output error during read on /dev/sda

and the installation stops.

I am selecting the option to erase and use the entire disk. I also tried doing manual partitioning - of the 60 GB hard disk I allowed 52 GB to be the root partition formatted as ext4, and the rest to be a swap area, but I still got the same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This may be the same problem as in [“errno 5 - input/output error” when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it sounds like your disk is dying. To confirm this, I suggest using a low-level disk integrity checking tool, like [Salvation HDD Scan and Repair](http://www.salvationdata.com/data-recovery-freewares/hdd-scan-c.htm)

Formatting the disk will only resolve problems at the filesystem level. If the aforementioned tool detects any errors, your only recourse will be to replace the disk.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this problem because of bad installation media. Download from torrent or [check the MD5 sums](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) against the ones [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too; I fixed it by changing the HDD to SATA mode in BIOS.

See [this post](http://forums.techguy.org/linux-unix/977983-solved-input-output-error-during.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try some diagnosis on your drive, the Ubuntu-live-cd has a pretty good disc-analysis-tool! Else try SystemRescueCd 1.6.0. These tests will give you an idea if your drive is still ok.

Comment: i ran the memtest 86 and it said that it was ok and test passed.

Comment: Sukrit, just run the Ubuntu10.4 live-cd. Select Try ubuntu. Then System->Preferences->Administration->Diskutility. Is your disc listed up? You can perform some tests here.

Comment: diskutility is showin my 60 HD but when i tried using benchmark it showed an error indetails it showed input/output error. i tried formatting,same error..